LWC DataTable not rendering custom picklist column correctly
I'm developing a Lightning Web Component (LWC) that displays records from a Salesforce screen flow in a data table. I'm trying to include a picklist column that edits the value of the Conceptos__c field for each record. The object being passed is Propuesta__c, and I've already created custom data types and templates for the picklists. However, when I run the screen flow and it renders the LWC, the column appears but not as a picklist, just a regular editable text field.
Here's an image showing the issue: Image of LWC with error
Image of LWC with error
Any ideas on why the column does not render as a picklist and how I can fix this?
Snippets:
MAIN COMPONENT JS AND HTML
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { FlowAttributeChangeEvent, FlowNavigationNextEvent, FlowNavigationBackEvent } from 'lightning/flowSupport';
import { refreshApex } from "@salesforce/apex";
import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
import PROPUESTA_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/Propuesta__c";
import CONCEPTOS from "@salesforce/schema/Propuesta__c.Conceptos__c";

const COLUMNS = [
    { label: '# CUOTA', fieldName: 'rowNumber', type: 'number', editable: false },
    { label: 'FECHA DE PAGO', fieldName: 'Fecha__c', type: 'date-local', typeAttributes: { dateStyle: 'short' }, editable: true },
    { label: 'CUOTA', fieldName: 'Cuota__c', editable: false },
    { label: 'VPN CUOTA IN. LISTA DE PRECIOS', fieldName: 'VPN_Cuota_in_Listas_de_Precio__c', editable: false },
    { label: 'VPN CUOTA', fieldName: 'VPN_Cuota__c', editable: true },
    { label: 'VPN CUOTA INICIAL PROPUESTA', fieldName: 'VPN_Cuota_inicial_propuesta__c', editable: false },
    { label: 'ENTIDAD FINANCIERA', fieldName: 'Nombre_entidad_financiera__c', editable: false },
    { label: 'ESTATUS', fieldName: 'Estatus__c', editable: false },
    {
        label: 'CONCEPTOS', fieldName: 'Conceptos__c', type: 'customPicklist', typeAttributes: {
            options: { fieldName: 'conceptoOptions' },
            value: { fieldName: 'Conceptos__c' },
            context: { fieldName: 'uniqueId' }
        }, editable: true
    },
    {
        label: 'ACCIÓN', fieldName: 'deleteAction', type: 'button', typeAttributes: {
            label: 'Eliminar',
            name: 'deleteRecord',
            iconName: 'utility:delete',
            variant: 'destructive',
            title: 'Delete Record',
            disabled: { fieldName: 'deleteDisabled' }
        }
    }
];

const SUMMARY_COLUMNS = [
    { label: 'Descripción', fieldName: 'description', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Valor', fieldName: 'value', type: 'number' }
];

export default class TablaRenegociador extends LightningElement {
    @api records;
    @api quoteId;
    @api propuestasToInsert;
    @track draftValues = [];
    @track summaryData = [];
    nextUniqueId = 0;
    conceptoOptions = [];
    columns = COLUMNS;
    summaryColumns = SUMMARY_COLUMNS;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, {
        objectApiName: PROPUESTA_OBJECT
    })objectInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValues,{
        recordTypeId : "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
        fieldApiName : CONCEPTOS
    })wirePicklist({data,error}){
        if(data){
            this.conceptoOptions = data.values;
        }else if(error){
            console.log('Error while loading data', error);
        }
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.updateRecords(this.records);
    }

    updateRecords(records) {
        this.records = records.map((record, index) => ({
            ...record,
            uniqueId: record.uniqueId || this.getNextUniqueId(),
            rowNumber: index + 1,
            deleteDisabled: record.Estatus__c === 'Pagado' || record.Estatus__c === 'Pagado parcial',
            conceptoPicklist: record.Conceptos__c
        }));
        this.calculateSummary();
    }

    getNextUniqueId() {
        return `unique-${this.nextUniqueId++}`;
    }

    handleRowAction(event) {
        const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
        const rowIndex = event.detail.row.rowNumber - 1;
        if (actionName === 'deleteRecord') {
            this.deleteLocalRecord(rowIndex);
        }
    }

    deleteLocalRecord(index) {
        const deletedRecord = this.records[index];
        this.records.splice(index, 1);
        this.records = [...this.records];
        if (deletedRecord && deletedRecord.id) {
            this.propuestasToInsert = this.propuestasToInsert.filter(record => record.uniqueId !== deletedRecord.uniqueId);
        }
        this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('propuestasToInsert', this.propuestasToInsert.length > 0 ? this.propuestasToInsert : null));
        this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success',
            message: 'Record removed from list and update queue',
            variant: 'success'
        }));
        this.calculateSummary();
    }

    addNewRow() {
        const newRow = {
            Fecha__c: '',
            Cuota__c: '',
            VPN_Cuota_in_Listas_de_Precio__c: '',
            VPN_Cuota__c: '',
            VPN_Cuota_inicial_propuesta__c: '',
            Conceptos__c: '',
            Nombre_entidad_financiera__c: '',
            Estatus__c: '',
            Cotizacion__c: this.quoteId,
            uniqueId: this.getNextUniqueId(),
            deleteDisabled: false
        };
        this.records = [...this.records, newRow];
        this.addRowIndex();
        this.calculateSummary();
    }

    addRowIndex() {
        this.records = this.records.map((record, index) => ({ ...record, rowNumber: index + 1 }));
    }

    handleSave(event) {
        const draftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
        let updates = [];

        this.records = this.records.map(record => {
            const draft = draftValues.find(draft => draft.uniqueId === record.uniqueId);
            if (draft) {
                const updatedRecord = { ...record, ...draft };
                updates.push(updatedRecord);
                return updatedRecord;
            }
            return record;
        });

        this.propuestasToInsert = updates.length > 0 ? updates : null;
        this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('propuestasToInsert', this.propuestasToInsert));
        this.draftValues = [];
        this.records = [...this.records];
        this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success',
            message: 'Changes saved and updated for flow',
            variant: 'success'
        }));
        this.calculateSummary();
    }

    calculateSummary() {
        const totalVPN = this.records
            .filter(record => record.Conceptos__c !== 'Separación')
            .reduce((total, record) => total + (parseFloat(record.VPN_Cuota__c) || 0), 0);

        this.summaryData = [
            { description: 'Total VPN', value: totalVPN }
        ];
    }

    finish() {
        this.propuestasToInsert = this.records.map(record => ({ ...record }));
        this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('propuestasToInsert', this.propuestasToInsert));
        this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Finish',
            message: 'All data has been prepared for insertion.',
            variant: 'success'
        }));
        this.dispatchEvent(new FlowNavigationNextEvent());
    }

    goPrevious() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new FlowNavigationBackEvent());
    }
}


<template>
    <lightning-card title="Propuestas" icon-name="custom:custom68">
        <div slot="actions">
            <lightning-button
                label="New Row"
                title="Add new row"
                onclick={addNewRow}
                icon-name="utility:add"
                class="slds-m-left_x-small">
            </lightning-button>
        </div>
        <lightning-datatable
            key-field="uniqueId"
            data={records}
            columns={columns}
            onrowaction={handleRowAction}
            draft-values={draftValues}
            onsave={handleSave}
            hide-checkbox-column
            show-row-number-column
            resizable>
        </lightning-datatable>
        <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
            <lightning-button
                label="Anterior"
                title="Anterior"
                onclick={goPrevious}
                class="slds-m-left_x-small">
            </lightning-button>
            <lightning-button
                label="Siguiente"
                title="Siguiente"
                onclick={finish}
                variant="brand"
                class="slds-m-left_x-small">
            </lightning-button>
        </footer>
    </lightning-card>

    <lightning-card title="Resumen" icon-name="custom:custom16">
        <lightning-datatable
            key-field="description"
            data={summaryData}
            columns={summaryColumns}
            hide-checkbox-column
            show-row-number-column>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </lightning-card>
</template>


CUSTOM DATA TYPE AND TEMPLATES
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import customPicklistTemplate from "./customPicklist.html";
import customPicklistEditTemplate from "./customPicklistEdit.html";

export default class CustomDataType extends LightningDataTable {
    static customTypes = {
        customPicklist : {
            template: customPicklistTemplate,
            editTemplate: customPicklistEditTemplate,
            standadrCellLayout: true,
            typeAttributes: ["options", "value", "context"]
        }
    }
}

<template>
    <lightning-combobox
    label="Concepto"
    variant="label-hidden"
    value={editedValue}
    data-inputable = "true"
    options={typeAttributes.options}
    ></lightning-combobox>
</template>

<template>
    <span class="slds-truncate">{value}</span>
</template>


